# Lifting state not working

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs

I was passing a function to the child components to modify the state of FilterableProductTable, when I do console log here is working properly even though it gives me this error 
'Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function
    at Object.handleInsertItems [as insertItems]'

```
   handleInsertItems(newItem){
    console.log(newItem);
         this.setState(prevState => ({
             active: prevState.active,
             items: prevState.items.concat('am')
         }));
```

anyway it is not updating the state of items or I cannot see the changes ,

```
class ProductRow extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state= {active: false};
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            active: !prevState.active
        }));
        this.props.insertItems(this.props.name);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <p  className={ this.state.active ? 'active service' : 'service' } onClick={this.handleClick}>
                {this.props.name}
            </p>
        );
    }
} 

 class ProductTable extends React.Component {
     render() {
         var rows = [];
         var lastCategory = null;
         var func = this.props.insertItems;
         this.props.products.forEach(function(product) {
             if (product.category !== lastCategory) {
                 rows.push(<ProductCategoryRow category={product.category} key={product.category} />);
             }
             rows.push(<ProductRow name={product.name} insertItems={func} />);
             lastCategory = product.category;
         });
    return (
        <div id="services">
            {rows}
        </div>
    );
     }
 }

 class FilterableProductTable extends React.Component {


         constructor(props) {
             super(props);
             this.state = {
                 posts: [],
             };
         }
         fetch() {
             axios.get(this.props.getSite)
                 .then(res => {
                     this.setState({
                         posts: res.data.functionality
                     });
                 });
         }

         componentDidUpdate(){
             this.fetch();
         }
         componentDidMount() {
             this.fetch();
         }
         render() {
             return (
                 <div>
                     <ProductTable products={this.state.posts} insertItems={this.props.insertItems}/>
                 </div>
             );
         }
     }

 export class App extends React.Component {

     constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.state= {active: true, items: ['noe']};
         this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
     }

     handleClick() {
         this.setState(prevState => ({
             active: !prevState.active
         }));

     }

     handleInsertItems(newItem){
         console.log(newItem);
         this.setState(prevState => ({
             active: prevState.active,
             items: prevState.items.concat('am')
         }));
     }

     render() {
         console.log('newITem');
         return (
             <div>
                 <FilterableProductTable
                     getSite={ this.state.active ? '/get_platforms' : '/get_features' }
                     insertItems={this.handleInsertItems}
                 />
                 <a className={ this.state.active ? 'button' : 'hidden' } onClick={this.handleClick}><span>Next</span></a>
                 <TotalComponent items={this.state.items}/>
             </div>

         );
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create bound versions of any functions passed through as params since the child component will not call the function with the correct context. In your constructor:

```
this.handleInsertItems = this.handleInsertItems.bind(this);
```